# Java move ui element smoothly

Tags: java, multithreading, qt, user-interface, qt-jambi

I`m trying to move my button upward using Thread.sleep() method in a loop. But elements just jumps to the end position after finishing the loop.

```
QPushButton upperBill = Globals.ui.firstUpperBillPushButton;

for(int i = 270; i >= -430; i -= 100)
    {
        upperBill.move(90, i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What issue may cause the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use QPropertyAnimation

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you for your answer. I`d like to find some book or tutorial in step by step learning qtjambi/qt to find the required information faster. Do you know some? I was looking for 2 days to find the solution for multithreading handling, until I heard about QTimer class :D